# Glob pattern argument for echo command

Tags: shell, wildcards, echo

```
echo *.c
```

in bash, treats the argument as a constant and prints `*.c`. How to force it to consider it as a `glob` pattern and print the list of files/folders ending with .c?

Comment: Your current directory doesn't contain any files/directory ending with `.c`, so `bash` left the pattern unchanged to `echo`. You can set `shopt -s failglob` to report error if pattern didn't match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either you have nothing in your current directory that match your globbing pattern (then the pattern will stay as it is), or you have disabled globbing by shell option `-f` (or `set -o noglob`).